# How to rename an application while developing with Quickly

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, quickly, pygi

I've been developing an application using PyGI and Quickly, and I now need to rename it. Is there any quick way to change all of the app name references in a Quickly application, or will I just need to do it by hand?

Comment: If there were a way to do it, I suspect it would be an invocation of `quickly configure`, but it looks like that just lets you change your ppa mapping

Comment: This is https://bugs.launchpad.net/quickly/+bug/667492 There's a script to rename projects attaced there, but it doesn't seem to work anymore. I find this really frustrating. Sometimes you just want to start coding and not have to think about the name you will present to users until latter.

Comment: Thanks @andrewsomething. Yeah, this has delayed my uploading of project code since the renaming becomes a hurdle that I can't squeeze into that hour-long window of energy on a weekday evening. I'll subscribe to that bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do this for my appshowdown application, and I would not try to do it all by hand.

What I did was make a new project with the correct name, and then paste in my custom code, and change a couple references to the old name in there. I then copied over the files for the gui, and did a find and replace on those for the new name.

It depends on how your code is organized. For me, the majority of my code was in a single file, so it was not too bad to get my application up and running after copying in the files for the interface.

Comment: Thanks @Jobi. I was wondering if that would be the way to go.

Comment: If you are so inclined, you may also want to delete the .bzr directory in the new project and copy the .bzr directory from the original project into the new one, to keep a history of previous commits. Then immediately issue: quickly save "Rename project"

Answer (score 2):

You will most likely have to do it all by hand. If you would like to see everything you can do in quickly you just need to open a terminal and run:

```
$: quickly commands
```